# how do you access a node in a node list that only occurs sometimes c# xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath, logic

```
    <OrderFeed>
<Order id="1">
    <BillingInformation>
        <Name>Bruce Ganek</Name>
        <Address>99 Main Street</Address>
        <City>Cranston</City>
        <State>RI</State>
        <ZipCode>02910</ZipCode>
    </BillingInformation>
    <ShippingInformation>
        <Name>Governor Chafee</Name>
        <Address>82 Smith St # 115</Address>
        <City>Providence</City>
        <State>RI</State>
        <ZipCode>02903-1121</ZipCode>
    </ShippingInformation>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo>
            <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description>
            <UnitPrice>10.50</UnitPrice>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
            <TotalCost>21.00</TotalCost>
            <CustomerOptions>
                <Size>M</Size>
                <Color>Green</Color>
            </CustomerOptions>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo>
            <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description>
            <UnitPrice>7.50</UnitPrice>
            <Quantity>3</Quantity>
            <TotalCost>22.50</TotalCost>

            <CustomerOptions>
                <Size>S</Size>
                <Color>White</Color>
            </CustomerOptions>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <PartNo>JETSFLASHLIGHT</PartNo>
            <Description>N.Y. Jets Flashlight</Description>
            <UnitPrice>5.00</UnitPrice>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <TotalCost>5.00</TotalCost>

            <CustomerOptions/>

        </Item>

    </Items>
</Order>
<Order id="2">
    <BillingInformation>
        <Name>Walt Disney</Name>
        <Address>DisneyWorld Hotel</Address>
        <City>Orlando</City>
        <State>FL</State>
        <ZipCode>32801</ZipCode>
    </BillingInformation>
    <ShippingInformation>
        <Name>Walt Disney</Name>
        <Address>DisneyWorld Hotel</Address>
        <City>Orlando</City>
        <State>FL</State>
        <ZipCode>32801</ZipCode>
    </ShippingInformation>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo>
            <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description>
            <UnitPrice>10.50</UnitPrice>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
            <TotalCost>21.00</TotalCost>
            <CustomerOptions>
                <Size>M</Size>
                <Color>Green</Color>
            </CustomerOptions>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo>
            <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description>
            <UnitPrice>7.50</UnitPrice>
            <Quantity>3</Quantity>
            <TotalCost>22.50</TotalCost>

            <CustomerOptions>
                <Size>S</Size>
                <Color>White</Color>
            </CustomerOptions>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <PartNo>JETSFLAG</PartNo>
            <Description>N.Y. Jets Flag for display</Description>
            <UnitPrice>5.00</UnitPrice>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <TotalCost>5.00</TotalCost>

            <CustomerOptions/>

        </Item>

    </Items>
</Order>
<Order id="3">
    <BillingInformation>
        <Name>Tom Brady</Name>
        <Address>One Patriot Place</Address>
        <City>Foxboro</City>
        <State>MA</State>
        <ZipCode>02035</ZipCode>
    </BillingInformation>
    <ShippingInformation>
        <Name>Tom Brady</Name>
        <Address>2121 George Halas Drive</Address>
        <City>Canton</City>
        <State>OH</State>
        <ZipCode>44708</ZipCode>
    </ShippingInformation>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <PartNo>JETPANTS</PartNo>
            <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatpants</Description>
            <UnitPrice>10.50</UnitPrice>
            <Quantity>3</Quantity>
            <TotalCost>31.50</TotalCost>
            <CustomerOptions>
                <Size>M</Size>
                <Color>Green</Color>
            </CustomerOptions>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo>
            <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description>
            <UnitPrice>7.50</UnitPrice>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <TotalCost>7.50</TotalCost>

            <CustomerOptions>
                <Size>S</Size>
                <Color>White</Color>
            </CustomerOptions>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <PartNo>JETSFLAG</PartNo>
            <Description>N.Y. Jets Flag for display</Description>
            <UnitPrice>5.00</UnitPrice>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <TotalCost>5.00</TotalCost>

            <CustomerOptions/>

        </Item>

    </Items>
</Order>
</OrderFeed>
```

I'm trying yo access the customer Options within an asp.net web services application. I can't figure out how to go through the Item node set using an XPath expression to get all Items including the Customer Options nodeset. I want the PartNo, Description, UnitPrice,Quantity, TotalCost and then customeroptions if there is any for an item. The tricky part is I get an exception because obviously I end up eventually try storing data that isn't listed for customer options in to a struct I made. This is what I have in my function for web services.

```
[WebMethod]
    public lab3 GetItemListForOrder(int OrderID)
    {

        string strFileName = Server.MapPath("~\\XML_OrderInfo_Lab3.xml");
        XPathDocument xDoc = new XPathDocument(strFileName);
        //XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
        XPathNavigator nav;
        XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;

        nav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
        string searchstring = "//OrderFeed/Order[ " + OrderID + "]/Items//Item";

        NodeIter = nav.Select(searchstring);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
        {
            lab3 lab = new lab3();
            XPathNavigator Items = NodeIter.Current;
            lab.PartNO = Items.SelectSingleNode("PartNo").ToString();
            lab.Description = Items.SelectSingleNode("Description").ToString();
            lab.UnitPrice = Items.SelectSingleNode("UnitPrice").ToString();
            lab.TotalCost = Items.SelectSingleNode("TotalCost").ToString();

            lab.Size = Items.SelectSingleNode("Size").ToString();
            sb.Append(Items.SelectSingleNode("Color").ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            return lab;
        }
    }
```

between the lab. TotalCost line and lab.Size, should be some kind of check to see if there is a customeroption available. I just can't figure it out and how to make it display correctly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for CustomOptions

```
while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
        {
            lab3 lab = new lab3();
            XPathNavigator Items = NodeIter.Current;
            lab.PartNO = Items.SelectSingleNode("PartNo").ToString();
            lab.Description = Items.SelectSingleNode("Description").ToString();
            lab.UnitPrice = Items.SelectSingleNode("UnitPrice").ToString();
            lab.TotalCost = Items.SelectSingleNode("TotalCost").ToString();

          var CustomoptionNode = Items.Select("/CustomerOptions");
          string Color = string.Empty;
           if(CustomoptionNode != null)
       {
            lab.Size = CustomoptionNode .SelectSingleNode("Size").ToString();
            Color = CustomoptionNode .SelectSingleNode("Color").ToString();

      }


   sb.Append(Color  + Environment.NewLine);

            return lab;
   }
```

Comment: This didn't loop through the if statement still. Also, when the method is invoked, it only returns the last item that was looped through.

Comment: This didn't work, It doesn't iterate through the if statement and inside the variable CustomoptionNode gets a null value stored. Also the output is still only showing the last item.

Comment: Chek the Updated answer.

Comment: I got the same result. It iterates, however it does get to the if statement and ask if the statement evaluates to true. For some reason it doesn't.

Comment: Update: It is going into the if statement. It is getting a system nullreferenceexception on the very last line.

Comment: i have done tying mistake in the 'CustomerOptions' node name, update and  check again.

Comment: I fixed it, I changed the statement to if (CustomoptionNode.HasChildren == true)...Now I have to figure out how I can output all three items instead of the last one. I can't put the return statement within the while loop because of scope issues.

Comment: You can create a List<lab3>, and add items in this list and return it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of Lists, now I just have to figure out how to get the nodes set with the strings to format it nicely. I appreciate it! Consider this one solved or answered.